# Boyd & Vandenberghe, exercise 3.43 — First order condition for quasiconvex functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

In the solution to Exercise 3.43 in Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook), the authors prove the first order condition for quasiconvex functions. In the proof there is a claim that says "there exists  $z \in [x_1,x_2]$ with $f(z) > f(x_1)$. Since $f$ is differentiable, we can choose $z$ that also satisfies $f(z) < 0$."

Since this is a textbook for students, I assumed that "this is easy to see", although I can't see it. Note that this is not follows directly from the mean-value theorem due to the constraint $f(z) >f(x_1)$. Few professors failed to answer. There are one or two related answers in this site but as the comments claim, they seem buggy.

So I formalize my question to the very elegant and independent short simple question below.

---

If $g$ is differentiable and $g(1)>g(0)$ then there is $x\in [0,1]$ such that $g(x)>g(0)$ and $g′(x)>0$.

Comment: Straightforward from Lagrange’s Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, just what I was looking for.
By this theorem there is $x$ such that $g'(x)=g(1)-g(0)>0$.
However, how can we guarantee that $g(x)>g(0)$?

Comment: Straightforward from drawing

Comment: I am looking for a proof.

Answer (score 2):

By replacing $g$ with $g-g(0)$, we may assume $g(0)=0$. Say $g$ is defined on an open set containing $[0,1]$. The assumptions read
$$g\text{ is differentiable at each $x\in[0,1]$, and } g(1) > 0,$$
and we want to show
$$\text{ there exists $z\in[0,1]$ such that $g(z)>0$ and $g'(z)>0$.}$$

---

Proof.
Let $$x_0= \inf\{x\in [0,1] : g(y) >0 \text{ for all }y\in [x,1] \} $$
As $g$ is continuous, (a) $0\le x_0 < 1$  and (b) $g(x_0) = 0$; Pictorially, $x_0$ "is the last zero of $g$".

By Mean Value Theorem, there exists $z\in(x_0,1)$ such that $g'(z) = \frac{g(1) - g(x_0)}{1-x_0}  > 0$. But by construction $g(z)>0$ also, QED.

---

proof of (a): Since $g(1)>0$, the set defining $x_0$ contains $1$, i.e. is not empty. Further,  by continuity of $g$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $g(y)>0$ for all $y\in [1-\delta,1]$. Consequently, $x_0\le1-\delta < 1$.

proof of (b) is similar: $g(x_0) = \lim_{y\downarrow x_0} g(y) \ge 0$. If $g(x_0)>0$, then by continuity, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $g(y)>0$ for all $y\in[x_0-\epsilon,1]$, violating the definition of $x_0$ as an infimum.

Comment: Thanks, although my proof below seems shorter and simpler.

Comment: @DanFeldman you're welcome. Well...if you strip off the proofs of (a,b) which are there only for completeness, my proof is "wlog $g(0)=0$ by translation, and wlog $g(x)>0$ for all $x>0$ by replacing the left endpoint with the last zero of $g$. Then the result is immediate by MVT (cf comments of insipidgenerator and LL3.14)." So I don't agree that involving $(g(0)+g(1))/2$ is simpler, but life would be boring if we all agreed :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $$ a := \max\left\{ y \in [0,1) \mid g(y) \leq \frac{g(0)+g(1)}{2} \right\} $$ By the mean-value theorem, there is $x\in (a,1)$ such that $g'(x)=\frac{g(1)-g(a)}{1-a}>0$. Moreover, $g(x)>g(0)$  by the definition of $a$. The maximum exists, since the set is closed (due to the $\leq$) and non-empty ($y=0$ is in it).

Buggy or half-proofs were suggested in the previous comments and in the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007482/proof-of-first-order-condition-for-differentiable-quasiconvex-functions). This is a joint work with Daniel Keren...