Subtlety within understanding proof of First Order Condition of Quasiconvex functions
Given $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable and $dom f$ is convex, we must prove
$$f \ \  \text{is quasiconvex iff} \\
f(y) \le f(x) \implies \nabla{f}^T(x)(y-x) \le 0
$$ for all $x,y \in dom f$.
The proof for ($\impliedby)$ in the solution goes something like this:
Assume $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ (the case for higher dimension can be proved by restricting to a line) and satisfies
$$
f(y) \le f(x) \implies \nabla{f}^T(x)(y-x) \le 0
$$
Suppose $f(x_1) \le f(x_2) \ \text{where} \ x_1 \neq  x_2$. Assume $x_2 \gt x_1$ without loss of generality. We need to show that $f(z) \le f(x_1)$ for $z \in [x_1,x_2]$ (i.e., $f$ is quasiconvex).
Now assume this is false. That is, there exists $z \in [x_1, x_2]$ s.t $f(z) > f(x_1)$. Since $f$ is differentiable, we can choose a $z$ satistfying $f'(z) \lt 0$.
However, by assumption, $f(x_1) \lt f(z) \implies f'(z)(x_1 -z) \leq 0 \implies f'(z) \ge 0$, which is a contradiction. Thus, $f$ is quasiconvex.
Now what I do not get is how we can choose such value $z$ that satisfies the inequality from the fact that $f$ is differentiable.
Like, how I understand this is that we are using MVT to find a specific $z' \in (x,y)$ s.t $f'(z') <0$. But how can we guarantee such $z'$ also satisfies $f(z') \gt f(x_1)$ (i.e., $z' = z$)?
From my understanding, the only truth we can establish is that there exists a specific $z$ satisfying $f(z) \gt f(x_1)$, but there is no guarantee that this is also $z'$?
I think I am misunderstanding things, but I do not know where to start from. Could anybody kindly provide guidance? Thank you.

Uhm there are some typos here for sure, for instance don't we rather want to prove $f(z) \le f(x_2)$ and not $f(x_1)$?

May not be the correct way to go, it's for general $x, y \in R^n$, we cannot assume vector dominance to start with

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007482/proof-of-first-order-condition-for-differentiable-quasiconvex-functions
